# Why am i able to declare another method with the same signature as one in the base class

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
internal abstract class Base
{
    internal abstract object Method1();
}

internal abstract class Base<T> : Base
{
    new internal abstract T Method1();
}
```

I have no idea why this is able to compile. Here are my questions:

1. Why am I able in a derived class to define another abstract method which differs only by the returned type.
2. <strike>Why does the new modifier even work on abstract methods? At lest from my point of view it doesn't make any sense because `Base` has no implementation for it</strike>

Of course I'm not able to create any non abstract class that actually inherits from `Base<T>` but why was I able to do this in the first place?

After the first set of comments look like there's some room for improvement:

> Why am I able in a derived class to define another abstract method
>   which differs only by the returned type.

This can be done even without the new keyword take for example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var obj = (Derived) new Object();
        int result = obj.Method1();
    }
}

internal abstract class Base1
{
    internal abstract string Method1();
}

internal abstract class Derived: Base1
{
    internal abstract int Method1();
}
```

The problems here are:

1. It is impossible to create a class which inherits from `Derived`
2. VS Intelisense tells you that there's an overload for that methods but it's just not able to display it.

While the answer might be that this doesn't make sense in the first place, I find this behavior a bit inconsistent because there are other places in the language when things which don't make sense cause a compile time error. An example is when trying to have a generic type constraint for a sealed or concrete value type.

As for my second question, it looks more like it's just a side effect of the first.

Comment: I mean, I don't see why you wouldn't be able to do this. Visual Studio does seem confused about implementing a class from this. It doesn't work like explicitly implementing interfaces does. Maybe this just exists because blocking it would be more difficult, or maybe there is a way to implement a derived class.

Comment: Because that's how the language was designed to work...<shrug>

Comment: You *are* hiding the base Method1, so the compiler likes you to add that `new` to signal that that was really your intent